# adding properties file for java chaincode

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I want add a configuration file that includes parameters like network name in a configuration file that the chaincode can read from and I can edit without reinstalling/instantiating the chaincode. Is this possible?

I have tried creating a config.properties files in the root project folder. I have the following code.

```java
try{
        FileInputStream ip= new FileInputStream("config.properties");
        prop.load(ip);
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("network"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("properties file not found");
    }
```

When running the chaincode unit tests I can see that the properties file are accessible and the value of network key is printed. When I deploy and go inside container logs, `properties file not found` is printed instead.

I did the following in my terminal and it reads the file.

`docker cp config.properties dev-peer0.org1.com-mycc-1.0:config.properties`

Is there a better way to do this? Or should I avoid reading from properties file since chaincode is not supposed to do any io operation.